# Material-UI BottomNavigationAction outside of BottomNavigation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to use the material-ui BottomNavigationAction component outside of the BottomNavigation but cannot work out how to show it as selected (change colour and show the label).

This simple code works and renders two icons, one of which is selected

```
import BottomNavigationAction from '@mui/material/BottomNavigationAction';
import EmailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Email';
import CallIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Call';


const Test = () =>
    <>
        <BottomNavigationAction key={1} label="Email" icon={<EmailIcon />} value="email" selected />
        <BottomNavigationAction key={2} label="Call" icon={<CallIcon />} value="call" />
    </>

export default Test;
```

However the 'selected' prop is not documented in the API and if I treat the file as a TypeScript file it generates the error:

> Property 'selected' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> BottomNavigationActionOwnProps & Omit<ButtonBaseOwnProps, "classes"> &
> CommonProps & Omit<...>'.

So, what is the 'right' way to render a selected BottomNavigationAction that will pass TypeScript validation?

Comment: What's the problem of using `BottomNavigation`? I think it does what you need, it acts like a group of "radio buttons" and you can choose only one of buttons.

Comment: If you want those 2 buttons to be selected at the same time, you can maybe wrap each BottomNavigationAction into it's own BottomNavigation?

Comment: Because I am trying to implement a Navigation Rail component https://m2.material.io/components/navigation-rail. The BottomNavigationAction does everything I need wrt display of labels and colour but I don't want to put it at the bottom of the screen.